# Unable to update changes to database after editing the gridview. There are no errors thrown, but changes are not updated in table in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

web config

```
<add name="MyConnection" connectionString="Data Source=HABIBDEA-PC;Initial Catalog=kopma;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=ilovedea1" />
<add name="kopmaConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=HABIBDEA-PC;Initial Catalog=kopma;User ID=sa;Password=ilovedea1"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="kopmaConnectionString2" connectionString="Data Source=HABIBDEA-PC;Initial Catalog=kopma;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=ilovedea1"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

1.there is my code to update.

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
 {
 TextBox nim = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtnime");
 TextBox status = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtstat");
 con.Open();
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update datauser set STATUSANGGOTA=@STATUSANGGOTA where NIM=@NIM", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STATUSANGGOTA",status.Text.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NIM", nim.Text.ToString());
            cmd.Connection = con;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();          
            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            gvbind();                 
}
```

2.this my connection string

```
public partial class UserAktif : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ToString());
    String s = "AKTIF";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gvbind();
    }
```

my aspx code

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="NIM" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable responsive" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NIM">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblnim" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NIM") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtnime" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NIM")%>' Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                                  </asp:TemplateField>     
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblstat" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("STATUSANGGOTA") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtstat" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("STATUSANGGOTA") %>' >                                     
                                </asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnedit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" CssClass="btn btn-info">Edit</asp:LinkButton><br />                      
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:LinkButton ID="btnupdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" CssClass="btn btn-success">Update</asp:LinkButton>
                                <br />

                                <asp:LinkButton ID="btncancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" CssClass="btn btn-danger">Cancel</asp:LinkButton>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>

                </asp:GridView>
```

can help me please ?
if i click update, no error, but no changes on database and gridview, tolong bisa gaa, kerjaan KP inih -.-

Comment: Where is your Connection string??? i.e con

Comment: i can't see your connection string but still you are saying no error is throwing it can be pblm with query..you are missing single quotes for the string in where condition.`update datauser set STATUSANGGOTA='" + status.Text.ToString() + "' where NIM = '" + nim.Text.ToString() +"'",con)`

Comment: not update database, but me update details of my code, still not change in database

Comment: ouh sorry, but now i use nim=@nim, and still not changes in database

Comment: @HabibWisnuP can you do a messagebox for both variable ??

Comment: what variable ? sorry, i'm bad english haha...but in same case, i create other web form that can edit all, but if i click updates, just photo can be updates, another field like nim,status, etc still same and not change in database

Comment: yes, this giving my exact value 1203040009

Comment: @Sachu yes, all of textbox giving exact value

Comment: done, but still same problem T.T

Comment: done, still same, ..... but finally i used default update command gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, i used default gridview update command
    i use this , perfectly work ^^

```
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:kopmaConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [NIM], [STATUSANGGOTA] FROM [datauser] WHERE ([STATUSANGGOTA] = @STATUSANGGOTA)" 
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE datauser SET [STATUSANGGOTA]=@STATUSANGGOTA WHERE [NIM]=@NIM">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="AKTIF" Name="STATUSANGGOTA" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

work fine for me